Make textures look blocky, without antialiasing
I'm interested in how to fix my OpenGL source code so that there is a blocky appearance to the textures - without antialiasing and multisampling, as it was in MS-DOS games. For example, I want the look in this screenshot:

I tried to change my shader's samplers to GL_NEAREST but that didn't change the result. The same goes for changing the antialiasing and multisampling settings:
GFX_GL_Sampler_Bind(&renderer->sampler, 0);
//GFX_GL_Sampler_Parameterf(
// &renderer->sampler, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT, 16.0f);

GFX_GL_Sampler_Parameteri(
    &renderer->sampler, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

GFX_GL_Sampler_Parameteri(
    &renderer->sampler, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

GFX_GL_Sampler_Parameterf(
&renderer->sampler, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT, 1.0f);

GFX_GL_Program_Init(&renderer->program);
GFX_GL_Program_AttachShader(
    &renderer->program, GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "shaders\\3d.vsh");
GFX_GL_Program_AttachShader(
    &renderer->program, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "shaders\\3d.fsh");
GFX_GL_Program_Link(&renderer->program);

glGenTextures(1, &m_TexID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_TexID);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, bih.biWidth, bih.biHeight,
        0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pRes_temp);
    
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);



If you find that disabling antialiasing in your code isn't producing a visible difference, it could be that your graphics driver is configured to automatically apply some kind of antialiasing on top. See if your graphics card has a control panel application where you can enable/disable features, and look for post-processing / antialiasing settings. These aliasing artifacts will also be more noticeable at lower resolutions, so if you're working on a high-DPI display, you might need to render to a smaller render target and upscale it.

Show us your output. Sometimes pictures can be better than 1000 words
